# how to create a view form option in java?

Tags: java, jform

I have created a form for getting the user details. Now I want that when the user clicks on submit button then his/her details gets displayed in an un-editable form format or a pop-up that shows how his/her forms look like.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use JPanel (as your un-editable form) and JLabel (to write your text), like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    NewJFrame1 frame = new NewJFrame1();
    frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel jlabel = new JLabel("Some kind of message");
    jlabel.setFont(new Font("Verdana",1,20));
    panel.add(jlabel);
    panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK)); 
    frame.add(panel, new GridBagConstraints());
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(NewJFrame1.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```